# GIT: Get Bash Here on network location

Tags: git

When I do 'Get Bash Here' on a network location the console isn't in that directory. Instead the directory is /c/Windows.

Is this a limitation of Git Bash?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is a limitation of Windows. The Windows "current directory" for a program cannot be UNC pathname, but must be a path with a drive letter. You will need to assign a drive letter to your network location.

You can either do this through the normal Windows Explorer method, or there's a shortcut command line to automatically create a drive letter:

```
pushd \\server\share\path
```

Run that in a usual Windows `cmd` shell, and it will allocate a new drive letter and change to it. Then you can use "Git Bash Here" on that drive letter and path from Windows Explorer.

Comment: That's great thanks! I just noticed that GIT actually gives me a warning: "UNC paths are not support. Defaulting to Windows directory."